# Find the CDF of Y in terms of conditional Ys

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Define a random variable $Y$ where it follows some probability distribution $F$:

$$
Y \sim F
$$

In other words, $F(y) = \mathbb{P}(Y \leq y)$ i.e. the CDF of $Y$. Now, for $k \in \{1,\dots,100\}$, define the random variable $Y_k$ as:

$$
Y_k =  Y \enspace | \enspace \frac{k-1}{100} \leq F(y) \leq \frac{k}{100} 
$$

Essentially, $Y_k$ is the distribution of $Y$ conditional on a specific percentile. For example, for $k = 2$, $Y_2$ is the distribution of $Y$ given that $Y$ falls within its second percentile, that is, $0.01 \leq F(y) \leq 0.02$.

Let $G$ denote the cdf of $Y_k$, so

$$
Y_k \sim G_k
$$

Question: How do I express $F$ in terms of $G_k$ for $k = 1,\dots,100$?

I'm allowed to assume, if it makes things simpler, that for each $A_k = supp(Y_k)$,

$$
\bigcap_{k \in \{1,\dots,100\}} A_k = \emptyset
$$

that is, the support of $Y_k$s do not overlap. But I'm not sure how it would make the derivation simpler.